# Laravel Routing Conflict issue

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I have following url in laravel:

1.Need to change From:

```
localhost/laravel/page/2/
```

to

```
localhost/laravel/2/
```

My Route.php is

```
Route::get('page/{id}/',
          array(
        'as'   => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page'));
```

But When I change to this,

```
Route::get('/{id}/',
          array(
        'as'   => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page'));
```

I have noticed that it has conflict issues with other route 
,Plz help me

Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the new routes at the last of your all other routes and also add a where clause, for example, try something like this:

```
//All other routes ...

Route::get(
    '/{id}',
    ['as' => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page']
);
```

Optionally you may add a `where` clause like this:

```
Route::get(
    '/{id}',
    ['as' => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page']
)
->where('id', '[0-9]+'); // for id as integer
```

Comment: Thanx,It works well, but if I want a {title} instead  {id} the,what will be in where condition..

Comment: In this case the `{id}` should be `{title}` and also in the where clause it should be `title` instead of `id`.

Comment: If that is string then it should be `[a-z]+` or you may remove the `where` clause completely.

Comment: My Route.php is                                                                                       Route::get('/{title}/',
    array(
      'as'   => 'page', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@page'))->where('title', '[a-z\-]+');
   
Route::get('blog',  array(
      'as'   => 'blog', 'uses' =>'Frontcontroller@blog'));
and my url is http://localhost/laravel/contact-us for pages But when go to http://localhost/laravel/blog it give me error ----Trying to get property of non-object (View: F:\wamp\www\laravel\local\resources\views\page.blade.php)

Comment: Just remove the where clause.

Comment: same issue after removing where clause

Comment: In case of id it is working,i dont need id,i want a title in my url

Comment: See in my error  when i go to localhost/laravel/blog it return view page.blade.php instead of  blog.blade.php becoz of my route